# apolloClient aborted after graphql request

Tags: vue.js, graphql, apollo-client

I'm trying to make a request to graphql api and it's aborting me after I added `no-cors`. Before this it was giving me this error `Access to fetch at 'https://venia.magento.com/graphql' from origin 'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

And now I'm getting this: `createHttpLink.ts:166 POST https://venia.magento.com/graphql net::ERR_ABORTED 500` with error message: `ServerParseError: Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at parseJsonBody`

Does anybody else has this problem ? And what could be the solution? Thank you for your answers:)

main.js:

```js
import { createApp, h, provide } from 'vue'
import './style.css'
import App from './App.vue'

import { ApolloClient, HttpLink, InMemoryCache } from '@apollo/client/core'
import { DefaultApolloClient } from '@vue/apollo-composable'

// HTTP connection to the API
const httpLink = new HttpLink({
  // You should use an absolute URL here
  uri: 'https://venia.magento.com/graphql',
  fetchOptions: {
    mode: 'no-cors',
  },
  headers:{
    'Content-Type': 'application/graphql',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
  }
})


// Cache implementation
const cache = new InMemoryCache()

// Create the apollo client
const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
  link: httpLink,
  cache,
})



const app = createApp({
  setup () {
    provide(DefaultApolloClient, apolloClient)
  },

  render: () => h(App),
})
app.mount('#app');
```

and this is my App.vue:

```html
<template>
  
</template>
<script setup>
import {useQuery} from '@vue/apollo-composable'
import { watchEffect } from '@vue/runtime-core';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';

const PRODUCTS_QUERY = gql`
query products {
  products(filter: {sku: {eq: ""}}, pageSize: 5, currentPage: 3) {
    items {
      name
      sku
      price_range {
        minimum_price {
          regular_price {
            value
            currency
          }
          final_price {
            value
            currency
          }
          discount {
            amount_off
            percent_off
          }
        }
        maximum_price {
          regular_price {
            value
            currency
          }
          final_price {
            value
            currency
          }
          discount {
            amount_off
            percent_off
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
`;

const { result, loading, error } = useQuery(PRODUCTS_QUERY);
watchEffect(() => console.log(result))
</script>
```